# EFI partition deleted; prefer to setup only efi bootable

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi, bios

During a clean install of Ubuntu, I partitioned the hard drive and removed the EFI (oops).

Now I can only boot from USB image in legacy mode. I'd like to boot using only EFI but am getting an error that there is no EFI found.

I've successfully created a small partition, formatted FAT32, and flagged as boot and  EFI.

I mounted the hard drive and tried running `grub-install` on the device but got this error:

````
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.```

my `/etc/fstab` I've setup while booting from the USB image and looks like this...

```# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=1d65fb47-b8e4-4efd-a2ad-6486ee92a1db /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=958b65c1-00a2-4deb-bcd9-e2415221ca39 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=f3aae6e2-e085-44bf-b0c5-fcbeee843fba none            swap    sw              0       0
````

main Question: What do I need to do to get an EFI partition working?

secondary Questions: What's the path of least resistance? Am I making any mistakes with the way I'm setting this up? Do I need to install ubuntu while in EFI?

Comment: Path of least resistance would be a reinstall of ubuntu with the EFI partition.  Make sure your install disk/USB is EFI, not old bios(done usually when making disk).  To learn, wait till someone else helps with instructions.

Comment: I think you forgot to put the "boot" and "esp" flags to your EFI partition. This can be done with Gparted.

Comment: Use `rufus` to create the live boot disk and while doing so choose efi instead of GPT BIOS

Comment: You need to totally uninstall grub & reinstall it in UEFI boot mode. Often easier with Boot-Repair and its advanced options. But if you can boot, you can uninstall grub-pc (BIOS version) and install grub-efi-amd64.